# Rails Form_with display inline error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to display the error message inline below the form elements in my rails application.

I did the following.

Controller

```
def create
    @faculty = Faculty.new(faculty_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @faculty.save
            format.html { redirect_to admin_faculties_path, notice: 'Faculty was successfully created.'}
            format.json {render json: @faculty, status: :created, location: @faculty}
        else
            format.html {render '_form'}
            format.json {render json: @faculty.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Form

```
    <% form_with(model: [:admin, @faculty]) do |f| %>
<div class="card-title">Add Faculty</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :faculty_name, class: "form-label" do %>
        Faculty Name <span class="form-required">*</span>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.text_field :faculty_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Faculty Name", required: true %>
    </div>
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

As I have some validations rules in Model, it checks the validations and stop the form from submitting if the validations occurs. As, this is the form_with form all the requests are handled by Ajax. So, I am looking to display the validations errors below the each form elements. Please suggest me with examples so that I can complete this task.

Comment: So do you wan to show errors message client side? on broswer before form submission?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct

Comment: Use bootstrap validations https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/validation/

Comment: Isn’t there any options to show the rails validation message which are stores as json error message

Comment: I need to show the validation error message to client side after submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for every attribute's [errors](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview-errors) on your form fields and if that attribute has any error just show them

```
<% form_with(model: [:admin, @faculty]) do |f| %>
  <div class="card-title">Add Faculty</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :faculty_name, class: "form-label" do %>
      Faculty Name <span class="form-required">*</span>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field :faculty_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Faculty Name", required: true %>
    <% if @faculty.errors[:name].any? %>
      <ul>
        <% @faculty.errors[:name].each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

A better solution could be refactor that on a [helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html):

**Helper**

```
module FacultyHelper

  def inline_errors(model, model_attribute)
    result = ""
    if model.errors[model_attribute].any?
         model.errors[model_attribute].each do |message|
            result += "<li>#{message}</li>"
        end
    end
    return "<ul>#{result}</ul>".html_safe
  end
end
```

**View**[UPDATE: wrapper for name errors]

```
<% form_with(model: [:admin, @faculty]) do |f| %>
  <div class="card-title">Add Faculty</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :faculty_name, class: "form-label" do %>
      Faculty Name <span class="form-required">*</span>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field :faculty_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Faculty Name", required: true %>
    <div id="user_name_errors">
       <%= inline_errors(@faculty, :name) %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

For remote: true, you need to define on your controller format.js

**Controller**

```
def create
    @faculty = Faculty.new(faculty_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @faculty.save
            format.html { redirect_to admin_faculties_path, notice: 'Faculty was successfully created.'}
            format.json {render json: @faculty, status: :created, location: @faculty}
            format.js
        else
            format.html {render '_form'}
            format.json {render json: @faculty.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

Create a corresponding js.erb view

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#user_name_errors").html("<%= inline_errors(@faculty, :name) %>");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried. The above logic works for non-ajax request.  I am getting the status: 200 form the XHR Request.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Here are some tips that you could use https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @SantoshAryal I updated the answer with a working example for remote that updates the new div wrapper user_name_errors with the inline_errors helper

Comment: thanks for the answer. It some how worked. Here is what I did. <% unless inline_errors(@level, :level_name).nil? %>
$(".invalid-feedback").show();
$(".level_name").html("<%= inline_errors(@level, :level_name) %>");
<% end %>
<% unless inline_errors(@level, :semester).nil? %>
$(".invalid-feedback").show();
$(".<%= :semester %>").html("<%= inline_errors(@level, :semester) %>");
<% end %>

Answer (score 1):

You can automate that by overriding `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`

1 - Create an initializer: config/initializers/fields_with_errors.rb

2 - Add this code to it.

```rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html_tag, instance|
    html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)
    element = html_doc.children[0]

    if element
        element.add_class('is-invalid')

        if %w[input select textarea select].include? element.name
            instance.raw %(#{html_doc.to_html} <div class="invalid-feedback">#{[*instance.error_message].to_sentence}</div>)
        else
            instance.raw html_doc.to_html
        end
    else
        html_tag
    end
end
```

Read more about it how it works https://dev.to/etoundi_1er/show-rails-validation-errors-inline-with-bootstrap-4-4ga6